# bot can't find any command in a cog

Tags: python, discord.py

im creating a bot with discord py, but it cant find any command that is in a cog. i've tried everything, here's my code

main:

```
import discord
import os
import asyncio

from discord.ext import commands

# Read the Data files and store them in a variable
TokenFile = open("./data/Token.txt", "r")  # Make sure to paste the token in the txt file
TOKEN = TokenFile.read()

OWNERID = 755431789987758140

intents = discord.Intents.all()

# Define "bot"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", help_command=None,intents=intents)

async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):

        if filename.endswith(".py") and not filename.startswith('__'):
            
            await bot.load_extension("cogs.{0}".format(filename[:-3]))

# Let us Know when the bot is ready and has started
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')


# A simple and small ERROR handler


@bot.command(name='ping')
async def ping(ctx):
        await ctx.send(f'**Pong!** Latency: {round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms')
# Run our bot

bot.run(str(TOKEN))
```

cog:

```
import random

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import slash_command

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

sites = ["sites" ]

ois_do_bot = ['oi', 'eae', 'eai', 'opa', 'epa', 'yo', 'alou', 'ola', 'Olá', 'epa', 'manda a braba', 'fala fi',
              'opa, bom?', 'oi, como estais?', 'chamou?']

respostas =  ['Não respondo a isso', 'Sim', 'As vezes', 'Não', 'Claro', 'NUNCA!', 'Um dia talvez',
                   'A resposta está dentro de vc', 'Mais ou menos', 'Podia ser pior']

class Fun(commands.Cog):
    """
    fun commands to make you happy :grin:
    """
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self._last_member = None

    @slash_command(name='pergunta', aliases=['d'])
    async def pergunta(self, ctx):
        """just ask something and it will answer you"""
        await ctx.send(random.choice(respostas))

    @commands.command(name='oi', aliases=[ 'eae', 'eai', 'opa', 'yo', 'ei', 'alou', 'ola', 'Olá', 'epa'])
    async def hi(self, ctx):
        """
        just send hi if you are feeling alone
        """
        await ctx.send(random.choice(ois_do_bot))

    @commands.command(name='dice', aliases=['roll'])
    async def dice(self, ctx):
        """
        roll a 6 sided dice
        """
        await ctx.send(random.randint(1, 6))

    @commands.command(name="site", aliases=["link"])
    async def site(self, ctx):
        """
        send you a funny site link
        """

        await ctx.send(random.choice(sites))


bot.add_cog(Fun(bot))
```

i tried literally everithing, almost re-wrote all the code and nothing, same error.
it keeps saying: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound:

i thought the problem was in the cog but it wasn't, then i tried looking in the main but i couldn't find too! any ideia?

sorry for my eng btw

Answer (score 0):

First, there's a simple way to register your cogs to your bot. For this case I'm using `class Client` for to do it

```
class Client(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("[your prefix here]")m
            case_insensitive=True,
            intents=discord.Intents.all()
        )
    async def startup(self):
        await client.wait_until_ready()
        await client.tree.sync()

    async def setup_hook(self):
        //assuming you put all of your cogs file in "cogs" folder 
        for filename in listdir("./cogs"):
            if filename.endswith(".py"):
                name = filename[:-3]
                await client.load_extension(f"cogs.{name}")
        self.loop.create_task(self.startup())

client = Client()
client.run([your token here])
```

Try reading the documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html#using-cogs)

Comment: hamm, it didin't work